# psql in windows

Tags: postgresql, aws, redshift

I want to connect to Amazon Redshift and run scripts like exports to s3 and loads through command line.

1. is psql the only way to go?
2. If that is the case, is there a package that would install just the psql CLI and not the entire postgresql server?

Comment: I believe that you will find all you need inside the `bin` directory of the [PostgreSQL Binaries](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload) It does not require installation (portable). Here is the list of binaries required for `psql`: `libeay32.dll, libiconv-2.dll, libintl-8.dll, libpq.dll, ssleay32.dll, psql.exe`

Comment: Works fine. Thank you very much for the answer